# jQuery - Custom plugin for toggling content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just did my first jQuery plugin which hides content that is too long.

You can view the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/denislexic/bT4dH/6/.

When you check it out and click on the "...", you ll notice that the first one toggles three times, the second toggles two times and the third one is correct (so just once).

I have no idea why it's doing that. I tried `e.preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation()`, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Here is the code that seems to be the problem:

```
 $("." + opts.clickZoneClass).on("click", function (e) {
    _debugger(1);

    var element = $(this).parent('div').children('div.status');

    // I know you can use is(':visible'), but it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8 somehow...
    if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        _debugger(2);
        element.animate({
            height:element.attr('data-toggle')
        }, 'fast');
        //$(this).html();
        element.removeClass('open');
    } else {
        _debugger(3);
        element.animate({
            height:element.attr('data-height')
        }, 'fast');
        element.addClass('open');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that if you add another paragraph, the first one will toggle 4 times.

Comment: And I was correct. I haven't found precisely why, but each "show more" button is getting a click listener for itself and each item after it. I would propose that is has something to do with sloppy scope.

Comment: Ha...that seems like a guarantee! Along that thought,I tried to take the click event outside the each...but it didn't help.

Comment: I don't know what sloppy scope is...

Comment: Look at where you are assigning the click event listener to the generated "show more" button. Make sure you aren't getting the previous buttons as well as the current one.

Comment: I tried putting it outside the return each...but it didn't work...hummm...I don't have any other ideas...

Comment: Use `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`after click call... this could be solve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're executing the above code in a $.each loop. If you pull out your binding code and just run it once your plugin works great.

I just pulled it out and moved it to the document ready function to illustrate...

http://jsfiddle.net/bT4dH/10/

Comment: I would obviously prefer to keep it inside the plugin, so that you call the pluggin, and it s done... I did try taking it out of the .each loop but it's the same problem.

Comment: Yes. You should keep it in the plugin. I was just illustrating that it was the cause of the problem. You shouldn't run the class selector inside the loop because the selector is running against the whole DOM, not just the context of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the click event is binding more than once when you iterating the element. To overcome this problem just add the unbind method before click i.e.

```
$("." + opts.clickZoneClass).unbind().on("click", function (e) {
    // existing stuff
});
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: That's an awful answer. That fixes the symptom, not the problem.